# Perl program to calculate the sum of the numbers that the user enters

Tags: perl, input, average

My script needs to get a series of numbers input by the user and find the average of them. I would like to use the line 'end-of-file' to show that the user is done inputting code. Any help would be appreciated. Below is what I have so far. I think I am really close, but I am missing something.

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;


print "Enter the scores and type end-of-file when done";
chomp(@scores = <STDIN>);
foreach (@scores) {
    push_average(total(@scores));
}




sub total {
    my $sum;
    foreach (@_) {
        $sum += $_;
    }
    sum;
}

sub average {
    if (@_ == 0) {return}
    my $count = @_;
    my $sum = total(@_);
    $sum/$count;
}

sub push_average {
    my $average = average(@_);
    my @list;
    push @list, $average;
    return @list;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close. Adding `use strict; use warnings` at the top of every Perl script will alert you of errors that might go unnoticed otherwise.

A few hints:

- You forgot the sigil of `$sum` in the last statement of `total`. Currently, you return a string "sum" (without strict vars), or possibly call a sub called `sum`.
- You don't need the `foreach` in the main part, rather do

  ```
  my @averages = push_average(@scores);
  ```

  The `total` is already calculated inside `push_average`
- You probably want to print out the resulting average:

  ```
  my $avg = $averages[0];
  say "The average of these numbers is $avg";
  ```
- The `push_average` is silly; you return a new array of one element. You could return that one element just as well.

---

Suggested script:

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;
use List::Util qw/sum/;  # very useful module

# say is like print, but appends a newline. Available with 5.10+
say "Please enter your numbers, finish with Ctrl+D";
my @nums = <STDIN>;
chomp @nums;

# The // is the defined-or operator
# interpolating undef into a string causes a warning.
# Instead, we give an expressive message:
my $avg = average(@nums) // "undefined"; 

say "The average was $avg";

sub average { @_ ? sum(@_) / @_  : undef } # return undef value if called without args
```

Comment: WOW. That was much simpler than what I was trying to do... How would you handle if it tried to divide by 0?

Comment: Just added the code to handle that: If the argument array `@_` is empty, `undef` is returned — this makes sense, as a 0÷0 is not defined. I test the return value of the sub for definedness, and possibly print out the string `undefined` instead. This makes for a nice user interface.

Comment: map{$y++,chomp,$x+=$_}<>;print$x/$y #don't do this ;)

Comment: @aidan `map` in void context? That is eeevil! → `$y++,chomp,$x+=$_ while<>;say$x/$y; #slightly better`, or `$y=()=map$x+=$_,<>;say$x/$y` (without strictures, numification is equivalent to `chomp`ing). Golfing the ultimate: `say$x/(()=map$x+=$_,<>)`

Comment: @amon awesome! I've been taught a lesson :)

Comment: great answers amon, most of your answers are a big lesson to me !! :)

Answer (score 0):

reads up to the newline. You've got a few choices here. You can ask the user to input the numbers separated by spaces and then split it into your @choices array. Or you can keep asking them to enter a number or just hit enter to finish.

Answer 1)

```
print "Enter scores separated by a space and press enter when done";
chomp($input = <STDIN>);
@choices = split(' ', $input);
```

Answer 2)

```
@chomp = ();
do {
   print "Enter a score and then press enter. If done, just press enter.";
   chomp($temp = <STDIN>);
   if($trim ne '') {
     push(@choices, $temp);
   }
} until ($temp eq '');
```